Unable to dump repository from SVN server
I am unable to dump a repository from an SVN server. The server is running on linux ubuntu. Whenever I run the command
sudo svnadmin dump /var/www/svn/repos/iteba > /home/ubuntu/iteba_repository.dump

it gives an error
svnadmin: E000002: Can't open file '/var/www/svn/repos/iteba/format': No such file or directory

and when I manually go to /var/www/svn/repos and ls there is no repo named iteba or any other repo.
But iteba is one of the repositories on this server and it is fully functional. It is accessible through TortoiseSVN the svn client. Developers are able to push data and extract data and it is also accessible at this url with its full content: http://52.7.99.98/svn/repos/iteba/. So the repo is available at the url and is accessible by svn client but not present in /var/www/svn/repos. I'm unable to take its dump. I'm also sharing apache sites enabled svn.conf content below.
<Location /svn/> DAV svn SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/ #SVNListParentPath On AuthType Basic AuthName "Test Repo" AuthUserFile /etc/svnpasswd Require valid-user </Location>

svn info command also works and shows info about iteba and svn list also list all repositories but I'm unable to take dump and repo is not visible in repos directory please help me resolve the issue.
I have tried every possible solution like by connecting with svn client and backup from there but that doesn't create the dump file I need to take dump from svnadmin dump so it includes all revisions and repository structure and everything.

The path to your repository is /var/www/svn/repos/, not /var/www/svn/repos/iteba/. You need pass the correct repo path to svnadmin.
